# Regarding docusign folder search - out for signature

Tags: docusignapi

I have used this api --> `url = base_url + "/restapi/v2/accounts/" + account_id + "/search_folders/out_for_signature"`. I got the actual response but along with the response awaiting my signature details also getting in same response.

I need to get only out for signature details alone not including awaiting my signature details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending it for yourself then in `/search_folders/out_for_signature` will include envelope which was sent to you. To fix this, what you can do is to call same URI with query parameters as `include_recipients=true`:

```
/search_folders/out_for_signature?include_recipients=true
```

Now in your code, iterate over all the envelopes and its signers, and check if `senderUserId` is same as `userId` inside "signers node. If yes then that envelope is sent to the `sender` also, and remove this envelope from your final list.